# Obtaining value from a <ng-tag>

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dropzone.js

I'm using ng-dropzone  [ng dropzone official page](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) and this is the code of when a file is uploaded on my page.

```
    <div class="dz-size">
        <span data-dz-size>
           <strong>0.1</strong>
           "MB"         
         </span>
<div>
```

I need to obtain that 0.1 value(that is the size of my image uploaded in ng-dropzone) in javascript through angular #1.5.8.

 **Is it possible to use angular (with `$scope.everything`) or Jquery(like `$("#mydiv").get(0)`) to obtain that 0.1 value ?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. What is "0.1" ? is it dynamic? Why don't you put this in your angular controller?

Comment: yes it's dynamic because it's generated from ng-dropzone library.
that 0.1 "MB" is the size of my image uploaded.
I would like to access the size of the uploaded image with dropzone